# Excel Formula Help: IF cell1 is equal to cell2, and number in cell3 is between x and y, then show cell4

Tags: microsoft-excel

This is my formula today (it works with the first 2 in dropdown menu (cell P2)):

"=IF(P2=DATA!D3;IF(AND(O4>=1;O4<2);DATA!G4;IF(AND(O4>=2;O4<3);DATA!G5;IF(AND(O4>=3;O4<4);DATA!G6;IF(AND(O4>=4;O4<5);DATA!G7;IF(AND(O4>=5;O4<6);DATA!G8;IF(AND(O4>=6;O4<7);DATA!G9;IF(AND(O4>=7;O4<8);DATA!G10;IF(AND(O4>=8;O4<9);DATA!G11;IF(AND(O4>=9;O4<10);DATA!G12;IF(AND(O4>=10;O4<11);DATA!G13;IF(AND(O4>=11;O4<12);DATA!G14;IF(AND(O4>=12;O4<13);DATA!G15;IF(AND(O4>=13;O4<14);DATA!G16;IF(AND(O4>=14;O4<15);DATA!G17;IF(AND(O4>=15;O4<16);DATA!G18;IF(AND(O4>=16;O4<17);DATA!G19;IF(AND(O4>=17;O4<18);DATA!G20;IF(AND(O4>=18;O4<19);DATA!G21;))))))))))))))))));IF(P2=DATA!D4;IF(AND(O4>=1;O4<2);DATA!J4;IF(AND(O4>=2;O4<3);DATA!J5;IF(AND(O4>=3;O4<4);DATA!J6;IF(AND(O4>=4;O4<5);DATA!J7;IF(AND(O4>=5;O4<6);DATA!J8;IF(AND(O4>=6;O4<7);DATA!J9;IF(AND(O4>=7;O4<8);DATA!J10;IF(AND(O4>=8;O4<9);DATA!J11;IF(AND(O4>=9;O4<10);DATA!J12;IF(AND(O4>=10;O4<11);DATA!J13;IF(AND(O4>=11;O4<12);DATA!J14;IF(AND(O4>=12;O4<13);DATA!J15;IF(AND(O4>=13;O4<14);DATA!J16;IF(AND(O4>=14;O4<15);DATA!J17;IF(AND(O4>=15;O4<16);DATA!J18;IF(AND(O4>=16;O4<17);DATA!J19;IF(AND(O4>=17;O4<18);DATA!J20;IF(AND(O4>=18;O4<19);DATA!J21;))))))))))))))))))))"

Cell P2 contains text from DATA!D3 to D6.
IF P2 equals DATA!D3 it fetches data from cell G4 if the number in cell O4 is bigger or equal to 1 and lower than 2.

I want to add DATA!D5 and D6 into that formula, but cell P2 shows as FALSE when I change it to DATA!D5 or D6.

Hope this makes sense and someone got good tips on how to make this work properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**better title labeling**

Your thread title maid me believe that your question is from a lazy person that is not able  to learn about simple formula basics which is in reality far from the truth.
I would relabel it into "How to implement 2-dimensional-lookups in excel?" instead.

**coding style for excel**

I make my sheets readible. Implement such formulas using a couple of cells to simplify debugging. Once you succeeded you can hide rows or columns as needed to focus on relevant cell contents when using your sheets.

**formula improvement**

You try to select a cell value dependant on the content of P2 and O4 by implementing
repetitive IF formulas.
In your case a simple formula relationship can be easily seen between the cells addressed and the O4 value.
Have a look at the excel INDEX function in its matrice version. Use the O4 value as parameter to select an element of a matrix. A single row or column is a matrix as well.
Eleminate fractional content of O4 by rounding the number down to a non-fractional one.

**handling just one dimension**

Using this solution you can compress a lot by writing

=index(g4:g21;rounddown(04;0);1)

instead of the whole

IF(AND(O4>=1;O4<2);DATA!G4;IF(AND(O4>=2;O4<3);DATA!G5;IF(AND(O4>=3;O4<4);DATA!G6;IF(AND(O4>=4;O4<5);DATA!G7;IF(AND(O4>=5;O4<6);DATA!G8;IF(AND(O4>=6;O4<7);DATA!G9;IF(AND(O4>=7;O4<8);DATA!G10;IF(AND(O4>=8;O4<9);DATA!G11;IF(AND(O4>=9;O4<10);DATA!G12;IF(AND(O4>=10;O4<11);DATA!G13;IF(AND(O4>=11;O4<12);DATA!G14;IF(AND(O4>=12;O4<13);DATA!G15;IF(AND(O4>=13;O4<14);DATA!G16;IF(AND(O4>=14;O4<15);DATA!G17;IF(AND(O4>=15;O4<16);DATA!G18;IF(AND(O4>=16;O4<17);DATA!G19;IF(AND(O4>=17;O4<18);DATA!G20;IF(AND(O4>=18;O4<19);DATA!G21;))))))))))))))))))

Keep in mind that the coordinates within the matrix are relative to itself and not refering to the whole sheet.

**handling the second dimension**

Increase the matrice so that it covers the whole lookup area like:

=index(g4:z21;rounddown(04;0);1)

Replace the "1" by the relative position in the matrix.
You would do some preprocessing by assigning a relative column coordinate for each of the four possibles text strings in P2.
You can do that using your IF clauses your with one VLOOKUP pointing to your translation table.

Comment: Did =INDEX(DATA!G4:DATA!G21;ROUNDDOWN(O4;0);1) instead of the whole string i had. Did it with each of the column J, M and P in DATA sheet. Thanks alot!